# Is there a word for the giver of a testimonial?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word for the author of a testimonial about a product or service. I thought perhaps "Testimonee" or something similar but that's not a word.

Comment: Based on this, I think 'referee' may work:

http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50291/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-is-willing-to-be-a-reference-for-someone

"a person appointed to examine and assess for publication a scientific or other academic work."

Comment: @KenGregory - No, a referee is one who *examines and assesses* a referee might then examine and assess the testimonials (say for publication) they do not author testimonials. That’s what a ***testifiier*** does.

Comment: @Jim - Fair point.  Perhaps 'reference' would have been a better suggestion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One who gives testimony, or attests, is an [attestant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attestant).  In your context of "product or service", you might want to also consider "reviewer".

Answer (score 3):

One who vouches for the quality of some product could be called a ***voucher***, which according to Merriam-Webster is "a person or thing that vouches for the truth of some statement, etc."

Answer (score 1):

**Oxford Dictionaries On-Line**, gives as its second meaning of ***referee*** (after the obvious sporting one):

***A person willing to testify in writing about the character or ability of someone, especially an applicant for a job***. (It is marked as *BRITISH*)

A third definition, which is not marked as necessarily British is:

***A person appointed to examine and assess for publication a scientific or other academic work***.

The second definition, in Britain, would appear to be the one you want. But if you are looking for something American I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: Yup, that's how this Brit says it.

Answer (score 0):

Product spokesman, spokeswoman, spokesperson.

Endorser.

"Publicly referenceable customer" is what one product marketing person at my company calls a customer that agrees to be cited publicly.